# Browse and Import local files with inline autocomplete?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, user-interface

Inline auto-complete is convenient:

[image]

Can it be extended to browse and import local filesystem?

I'm aware of the [[Experimental]] (since V 9?) [AutoComplete](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Autocomplete.html) could be used interactively with `FileNames`.

Browsing the [`Autocomplete` Q`s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=autocomplete) however there are many issues, though it works fine for built-in symbols, including user-defined, but doesn't autocomplete user-defined strings.

So this is more a system question.

Note, If caching is needed for efficiency, the entire filesys could be mirrored as a nested `Association` trie, up to memory.

Comment: when I type `Import["C:` popup for file browsing appears.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks, DNK, works in OSX too. If you rewrite as A, will accept.